# Tricking TPS signals with a Voltage Source

Tags: electrical, electronics, throttle-position-sensor

Good evening,

I am trying to trick the TPS by disconnecting the two APP1 and APP2 signals and connecting them to a voltage generator that generates a voltage that is within the range of both APP1 and APP2 signals. My question is:

- Is this possible? Should I connect the ground of the generator to the ground of the TPS and the two voltages to the two signals cables?

Thanks,

Enzo

Comment: While to my knowledge this is something you could do ... I'm wondering the "why" behind it. There's a reason there's a TPS, that being to tell the computer what someone is trying to command for power and to understand the amount of air which is coming into the engine. Faking it is only going to cause issues with how the engine runs.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The reason why I am doing his is that I am making a project that consists of making a throttle that is a potentiometer and with a microcontroller, I will be able to output these voltages. My TPS has 6 pins, if I connect a multimeter to pins number 2 and 5 I get the first APP signal and if I connect it to pins 2 and 6 I get the second signal. Should I connect ground to pin 2 and pin 5 and 6 to the voltages that I generated? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Presuming you're describing a drive by wire system consisting of dual accelerator pedal position sensors, dual throttle position sensors, a servo motor opening/closing throttle plate and the ecm as the master, are you trying to circumvent throttle position sensors feeding back signals to the ecm? Are you aware the two APP pedal signals are sent directly to the ecm, the ecm commands the throttle servo motor into position with the dual tps' feeding back position signals to the ecm with the ecm correlating apps and tps' to accurately move throttle according to pedal position sensors?

Comment: Would be good to tell us which car this is for and why you are doing this.

Comment: @FDryer Thanks for your comment, yes the system is a drive-by-wire system and I am trying to connect the two APP signals that go to the ECU with my voltage signal that are the same as the TPS voltage signals.

Comment: The low voltage reference used for APP!/APP2 and TPS1/TPS2 have ground return, The varying signals are input to the ecm. You should have factory wiring diagrams when attempting advanced modififications to eliminate guessing. The two APP signals may be considered masters, telling the ecm to open/close throttle servo motor while the dual TPS' feed throttle position to the ecm as slaves. Pedal/master, tps'/slave signals. TPS' tells the ecm throttle plate position.